# For loop not working for negative values - java

Tags: java

I'm new to programming, so would welcome any kind help.

I was doing revision on a for loop and i realise that my negative values would not be displayed. Why is this so?

I don't see anything wrong with my codes..

```
for(int x = -5; x > 5; x+=2) {
    if(x - decrement >= -5) {
        System.out.println(x + ", ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you made a typo: `int x = -5; x > 5; x+=2` should be `int x = -5; x < 5; x+=2`

Comment: well you loop as long as `x is greater than 5`, since `x=-5` there nothing this loop will do, because the condition to loop isn´t fullfilled at the start.